# Cant get my code to run

Tags: prolog

I'm really desperate about this question (I'm not very good with Prolog).
I'm asked to create a reductionTheosophique,
in other words I have to do the following:

If I'm given, lets say, `123`, I'll need to return the sum so: `1+2+3=6`. 
This is what I got so far.

```
reduction(X,R) :-
   X >= 0,
   K is (K + (X mod 10)),
   T is  (X//10),
   reduction(T,R),
   R is K
```

`65=6+5=11=1+1=2` :(

I'm still working on it... Thank you!

Comment: Once a variable like `K` is instantiated inside a predicate clause, it cannot be reassigned without backtracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
reduction(0, 0) :- !.
reduction(X, R) :-
    X2 is X // 10,
    reduction(X2, R2),
    R is ((X mod 10) + R2).
```

Part of the problem with your code is that you wrote `K is (K + (X mod 10))` and that could only ever be true when `K` is already a number and `X` is `0`.

---

Here's a version that continues to reduce:

```
reduction(0, 0) :- !.
reduction(X, R) :-
    X2 is X // 10,
    reduction(X2, R2),
    R is ((X mod 10) + R2),
    R < 10.
reduction(X, R) :-
    X2 is X // 10,
    reduction(X2, R2),
    R1 is ((X mod 10) + R2),
    R1 >= 10,
    reduction(R1, R).
```

It certainly could be reduced down a bit more, but that would require a bit more thinking that I'm two glasses of red past being able to do. :-)

Comment: im a newbie to this language, i forgot to mention that if the answer is a double digit number, i will have to sum it as well: 65=6+5=11=1+1=2 :(

Comment: The cut makes `reduction(0,1)` loop instead of failure.

Comment: @false - I don't get a loop. I get immediate failure.

Comment: Oh, you are right. But still: this is more luck than anything else: `// 10` will ultimately end in 0. So a test `X > 0` after the head would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bit simpler (I'm on my second cup of coffee, no wine ;)):

```
reduce(N, N) :- N < 10, !.
reduce(N, R) :-
    N >= 10,
    Y is N // 10,
    reduce(Y, R1),
    R2 is (N mod 10) + R1,
    reduce(R2, R).
```

Examining your original attempt:

```
reduction(X,R) :-
   X >= 0,
```

You could check `X >= 10` here instead of checking `>= 0` and include a needed *base case*, as I have done above, for `X < 10`. Without the base case, your predicate will always ultimately return failure or loop infinitely since there's no valid case for `X < 0` and no other clauses.

```
   K is (K + (X mod 10)),
```

The `is/2` predicate is for evaluating fully instantiated arithmetic expressions on the right hand side (second argument to `is/2`), and instantiating the variable on the left (first argument to `is/2`) with that value. Here, `K` doesn't have a value, so you'll get an **instantiation error** from Prolog. If `K` did have a value, it would still necessarily fail unless `X mod 10` happens to be zero because you are saying, in Prolog, that the value of `K` is the value of that same `K` plus `X mod 10`, which of course, is impossible if `X mod 10` is not zero.

```
   T is (X//10),
```

This seems OK, since `X` is known.

```
   reduction(T, R),
   R is K.
```

These two together are a problem. Assuming that `reduction(T, R)` succeeds as you wish it to (which it wouldn't due to the above problems), `R` would be instantiated, then the following expression `R is K` would fail unless `K` was instantiated and already had the same value as `R`. This is also a common mistake by prolog beginners to "assign" one variable to another, like in imperative languages. You really were trying to *unify* `R` and `K`, which is done with `R = K`.

Comment: Great explanation, cant thank you enough. i think ill grab a glass of wine to digest all these information. lmao